# Insert large array into a SQL Server table variable with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have an integer list and I'm trying to insert those values into a table variable, declared with [DECLARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement, using Dapper. I've tried several combinations, but ultimately it leads to `Incorrect syntax near ','` error.

Can Dapper even differentiate between a local variable and a Dapper query param, both being with `@` prefix?

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5xOaA)

```cs
List<int> output = null;
        
List<int> input = new List<int> 
{
    1, 2, 3
};

var sql = @"DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (Id INT)
            INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@Ids); 
                    
            SELECT * FROM @tempTable;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServer()))
{
    output = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { Ids = input }).ToList();
}
```

Note that the input list can be bigger than 1000.

Comment: You are using an anonymous array :new { Ids = input }.  Instead make it an int[] : new int[] {1,2,3}

Comment: @jdweng Isn't that the same as just passing `input.ToArray()`, which generates error: `An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper will transform the list into seperate parameters, suitable for inclusion in an IN predicate, but not an INSERT ... VALUES query.  Instead pass the values as JSON, which is also much, much cheaper for large lists than using separate parameters.  EG

```
List<int> output = null;

List<int> input = new List<int>
    {
        1, 2, 3
    };

var sql = @"
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (Id INT)
INSERT INTO @tempTable(id) select value from openjson( @Ids ); 
        
SELECT * FROM @tempTable;";

var inputJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(input);

using (var con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true;trust server certificate=true")) 
{
    output = con.Query<int>(sql, new { Ids = inputJson }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but bear in mind from the Microsoft docs: 
OPENJSON requires Compatibility Level 130
The OPENJSON function is available only under compatibility level 130. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server can't find and run the OPENJSON function. Other built-in JSON functions are available at all compatibility levels.

You can check compatibility level in the sys.databases view or in database properties.